# native python - dataframe for loop and insert records to db

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark

I am working on AWS Glue, and so I cannot use Pandas/Numpy, etc currently.

I have a dataframe of records, which I need to process and update to mysql database.  I need to check for record availability and already exists, do an **insert...on duplicate key**.  For this reason, I need to loop through the dataframe using native python libraries.  All dataframe iterators I found were using pandas, but is there a way to do without pandas?

Please find herewith a sample dataframe:

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ('4001','81A01','Portland, ME','NY'),
    ('4002','44444','Portland, ME','NY'),
    ('4022','33333','BANGALORE','KA'),
    ('5222','88888','CHENNAI','TN')],
    ("zip_code_new", "territory_code_new", "territory_name_new", "state_new"))
```

I tried the following, but i got an error message, "**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'values'**"

```
for i in df1.values():
    print i
```

**UPDATE**: The following code seem to work with native python to loop through the dataframe.   Also, psidom's code also should work, but i could not see the print results.

```
arr = df1.collect()
  for r in arr:
      print r.zip_code_new
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use for loop on spark data frame; It has `foreach` method to loop through rows; for example, we can print the `zip_code_new` in each row as follows:

```
def process_row(r):
    # your sql statement may go here
    print('zip_code_new: ', r.zip_code_new)

df1.foreach(process_row)

#('zip_code_new: ', u'4002')
#('zip_code_new: ', u'5222')
#('zip_code_new: ', u'4022')
#('zip_code_new: ', u'4001')
```

Comment: hi thanks, I tried similar to above, though execution result says FINISHED, but am not seeing any console output, ie., r.zip_code.  The print statement is not executed.  Should i import any library for this?  thanks.  I am using PYSPARK / zeppelin

Comment: hmm. I tested this in a local environment. And if you have a real cluster, you won't see the print as it's happening on the worker node.

Comment: I used arr = df1.collect(), followed by for r in arr:.  This seem to work.  Performance wise, will this have any impact? Thanks Psidom

Comment: If your data frame is not large, then it's a perfectly workable solution; Otherwise, you might get memory error and it could potentially be slow as everything happens on the driver only.